# Contribution email receipt with custom fields shows array in template

Tags: custom-fields, receipts

Using default contribution receipt message template, the receipt email shows `"array"` rather than `custom field values`.  It works correctly if no custom fields are used in profile.

This seems like this issue which does not seem to be closed.
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=27587.0

Using `Civi 4.6.8`
[image]

Comment: I just tested this out and `custom_fields` used  for Contribution are properly retrieved in the mail. Can you provide some more details, screenshot, etc ? eg. Type of the `custom_field` ?

Comment: I have done more testing and the problem is not consistent.   Where might I look for error details that would better indicate the cause of the problem?   Thanks for help.

Comment: More testing - seems to work OK if I am logged in (as admin user) but not if I am completing form as an anonymous user (using Drupal).   Profile permissions are checked for anonymous user.  Are there other permissions that might be necessary to complete a membership contribution page with profile?

Comment: I have checked and rechecked permissions including profile, contribute permissions.  The form successfully creates new contacts with all of the profile information.  Any different permissions that would affect the email receipt template behavior?

Comment: Can you recreate this on our sandbox site http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/. If yes, then it seem to be a bug in core:(

Comment: It first showed up as a problem in receipts sent immediately after upgrading to 4.6.8 on 8/28/15.   I don't think I can trigger an email from the demo site.

Comment: Further testing - giving anonymous user ALL permissions, it still does not populate the array when logged out when completing the contribution form for membership.  Is there something about email receipt template (Smarty?) that would care whether the form is completed by a logged in user or not?